# Login to a backend account with facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I have an iOS app that when you login or create an account, it logs in/signs up with a backend that I've created that stores all information.

The problem is, when I use the facebook SDK to login, I can't find any unique information that I can store to authenticate that use in the future.

For example, if I have an user login with their email address, they authenticate with their email and password, then in the future, when I make an API call, I authenticate all those calls with the users unique token, which lives on the iOS app and server, and when that token expires, it sends a new one to the iOS app so I can continue to communicate.

What can I do to get from the facebook API that I can store on my server that I can use to authenticate the user with?

I know there is a token, but that expires really quickly. I'm using facebook iOS SDK 4.7.0

Comment: To identify Facebook users, you should only use the Facebook user id that you get from the API when you request basic user details with their token. Keep in mind that although it does currently contain only digits, it is not meant to be interpreted or stored as an integer, but as a string value. (As it might start to include other characters at any point in the future.)

Comment: But I can't use that value to authenticate a user on my server, because anyone get get a facebook users email and id, and then would defacto know a users username and password to use my API, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to send the access token that you get back to the server. On the server, combine you access token and your app id to get an appsecret_proof. The appsecret_proof is a sha256 hash. Make a request to facebook that looks like this:

```
curl \
  -F 'access_token=<access_token>' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=<app secret proof>' \
  -F 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/friends?limit=50"}]' \
  https://graph.facebook.com
```

If you get a successful response, you know that it was a legitimate request and can log the user in. The cool part is that the access token expires. If you wait too long to make the request, you'll get a failure back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190,
    "error_subcode": 460,
    "fbtrace_id": "GG1nF4eGYKI"
  }
}
```